# mysql query for checking a match in either csv string

Tags: mysql, csv

will try to explain the requirement as much as possible. 
there is a comma separated string list for a person's interest . for example following example for 2 people

```
P1: "hockey, cricket, IT"
P2: "TV, football, cricket"
```

now the aim is to check if there is any matching values with a certain user of other users. in above example, we should get cricket from the list.

Any help in a mysql query for this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you have control over the schema, change it now.  Each interest should be a separate row in a lookup table, with a mapping table between people and interests.  It will have many (many!) benefits, aside from making it trivial to find people with the same interests.

Comment: @AlainCollins thank you for the comment. will convey the schema option to the project lead. however just for the sake of understanding, do you think under this schema , the required task is achievanle ?

Comment: How about doing some basic research before asking next time? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+search+comma+separated+value

Comment: If you follow [proper database normalization strategies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) you won't create more work for yourself in the future.

Comment: It might be possible to REPLACE the commas in the interest string to create a value that could be used as the AGAINST portion of a MATCH clause.  Now, remember when I said that changing the schema would have many benefits?  :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this way:

```
    $string1 = 'hockey, cricket, IT';
    $arrP1 = explode(',',$string1);

    $string2 = 'TV, football, cricket';
    $arrP2 = explode(',',$string2);

    $strResult = array_intersect($arrP1, $arrP2);

    print_r($strResult);//cricket
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most fancy option but sometimes you have no choice.
First create a numbers table. (just a table with enough numbers from 1-maxitems in csv string).
Then create this function:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION `CsvMatch`(`csv1` VARCHAR(255), `csv2` VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN   
    DECLARE returnVal VARCHAR(255);

    SELECT result INTO returnVal FROM (
        SELECT
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(csv1, ',', numbers.number), ',', -1) result
        FROM 
            numbers WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(csv1) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(csv1, ',', ''))>=numbers.number-1
        HAVING FIND_IN_SET(result,csv2)
    )d LIMIT 1;
    RETURN returnVal;
END
```

Call this using:

```
SELECT CsvMatch('123,321,222','555,321,551'); # returns 321
```

It wil return the first match or NULL.